# MongoDB Sort documents by the most recents of three fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

I would like to sort a collection by the most recent field of three ones.

Imagine each one of my documents has a field `dates` with 3 dates inside.

```
{
    ...,
    dates: {
        dateOne: "2010-01-01"
        dateTwo: "2020-01-01",
        dateThree: "2015-01-01",
    },
    ...
}
```

I want to fetch my documents sorted by the most recent date of `dates`, `dateTwo` in this case, but the most recent could be `dateOne` in another document.

Knowing that there could be the three fields or only one as there could be two.

Comment: You can try an aggregation query with `$facet` stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$max` operator can take a list of fields to compare. It will return the largest one. It's okay with fields that don't exist, so it doesn't matter if a document is missing `dateTwo`, for example.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
            key: 1,
            dates: 1,
            latestDate: {
                $max: [
                    "$dates.dateOne",
                    "$dates.dateTwo",
                    "$dates.dateThree"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            latestDate: 1
        }
    }
])
```

([example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zvrEuXnsanR))